# Fusion Table Syncing with Google Forms: Exception: Invalid query: Parse error near

Tags: mysql, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to get information to automatically sync. 
This is the script I used: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/lclontz/google_forms_to_fusion_tables/blob/master/script%20for%20Google%20forms.txt).

The error is: Exception: Invalid query: Parse error near 's' (line 1, position 621)

All the empty "" are just because those fields were not filled out on the form.

Problem running SQL: 
INSERT INTO lots of text

VALUES ('Sat Mar 05 2016 14:20:54 GMT-0500 (EST)','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','No','First','Last','None','1 New York Drive','New York City','NY','00.000000,-00.000000','12345','email@gmail.com','###-###-####','###-###-####','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''): Exception: Invalid query: Parse error near 's' (line 1, position 621).. (line 327, file "Code")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes in strings must be escaped with a backslash,

e.g.

```
'Applicant's Firsts Name:'
```

must become

```
'Applicant\'s Firsts Name:'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I just removed the ' because I am not sure if there is a way to have them in the table only and not in the form and spreadsheet.